# Change properties of an unknown object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, properties, casting, object

I have a sub that handles when 14 ComboBoxes have their Index changed. I am able to cast the sender of the event, and obtain properties from there. However, after that, I want to be able to change the properties of the actual sender, rather than the cast one. How would I do this?

Current code:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxIndexChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged [etc]
        Dim myComboBox As ComboBox = sender

        Select Case myComboBox.Text
            Case "Will"
                Me.Controls(myComboBox.Name).Text = "555-555-555"
            Case "Bob"
                Me.Controls(myComboBox.Name).Text = "555-124-1234"
            [etc]
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I am currently trying to use

```
Me.Controls(myComboBox.Name).Text
```

But I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean with "the actual sender"?

Comment: The object that triggered the event in the first place.

Comment: But that is the combo box... you already have the object: `myComboBox`.

Comment: Yes, but I can only modify the properties of that instance of it. I want to modify the properies of the actual object that sent the even, not an instance of it.

Comment: @blake: I am sorry, but that does not make any sense. *An object is an instance of a type*. In this case `myComboBox` is an instance of the type `ComboBox`. You cannot alter the type `ComboBox` in your code, you can only manipulate instances of it.

Comment: I'm sorry I got the wording wrong. I do not want to alter the type, I only wanted to alter an instance of it. I had no idea that it was a reference, so obviously this would appear to be a stupid question to a proficient VB coder.

Comment: @blake: the only questions that are stupid are those that you don't ask because you think they are too stupid, because then you don't learn. Believe me, this scenario has bewildered me as well in the beginning of my coding adventures :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` parameter in an event handler will (typically) contain a reference to the object that raised the event. In the case of the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of a `ComboBox` control, it will be the `ComboBox` that had its `SelectedIndex` property changed. So in your code sample above `myComboBox` is referring the `ComboBox` that raised the event.

To clarify: if you select an item in the drop-down list of a `ComboBox` control, so that it raises the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, the sender parameter of the event handler will be *that same `ComboBox`*, not a copy of it. This is true for all reference types.

Had it been a value type raising the event it would have been a completely different story, but that is a very rare case (it it is never the case when it comes to controls on a form).

Answer (score 1):

ComboBox is a reference type, so if you assign directly to the Text property of the myComboBox variable, it will update the control.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea it was a reference. I have just done some debugging and it does in fact change the text property of the ComboBox, but instantly after it it changed back to it's original value (in this case "Will"). Any idea what is happening?

Comment: @blake: it's not a good idea to set the `Text` property in a combo box in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event; when the user selects an item in the list, the control will automatically set the `Text` to the text of the selected item.

Comment: In what event could I change it then? All I want is for the user to choose the name of the person in the Combo Box, which then appears as their telephone number.

Comment: I would need more information about your debugging session to answer that. Maybe the variable is now pointing to a different control? Maybe another event is resetting the Text property?

Comment: @blake: I would find that behavior rather confusing, as a user. Perhaps you should include the phone number in the text in the list instead, as `"Will (555-555-555)"`. The other option is to make the ComboBox OwnerDrawed, but that will be rather complex.

Comment: Ah, I see. In my opinion you should not be using one UI widget to display two different pieces of data, but if you want to stick with that design, then you will have to sprinkle a lot of safety checking code around several different event handlers.

Comment: I think a two object solution will be much easier for everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 Dim ctl As Control
 Dim cmb As ComboBox

 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
   If sender Is ctl Then
     cmb = ctl
     cmb.Text = "string"
     End If
   Next ctl
```

You can add the specific string assignment code in place of cmd.Text = "string". Assigning cmb allows you to use the specific combobox properties rather than the generic control properties.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question of why you were getting a null object reference exception, is the Control you are searching for a direct child of the Form? Does it sit in a panel or some other container on the form? If so then I don't think you will find that control in the Form's Controls collection. So this line:

```
Me.Controls(myComboBox.Name).Text
```

Only searches through the forms direct children and not recursively through the children of those controls.

Answer (score 0):

If I using the following code, I will get the same err: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Me.Controls(TBName).DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, dt.Columns(colindex).ColumnName)
```

Sugestion from Christian Pena fit my case, so the right code should be:

```
Me.TCAll.TabPages(0).Controls(TBName).DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, dt.Columns(colindex).ColumnName)
```